# Any similar tools like Fiddler's AutoResponder?

Tags: boot, parental-controls, fiddler

So, I was looking for a parental control that could block my children from some unwanted websites and redirect them elsewhere.
As far as I searched, I found this handy Fiddler tool. It does all that I need, but it lacks options, like running at boot and something like "ninja mode" where my children can't try to access the program down from the toolbar.

Do you know any such similar tool with the features I described above?

Answer (score 2):

You could try running fiddler as a service as outlined here - it might do what you are looking for

http://fiddler.wikidot.com/runasservice